# selecting indexes with multiple years of observations

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I wish to select only the rows that have observations across multiple years. For example, suppose

```
mlIndx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('x', 0,),('x',1),('z', 0), ('y', 1),('t', 0),('t', 1)])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(6,2)), columns = ['a','b'], index=mlIndx)


In [18]: df
Out[18]:
      a   b
x 0   6   1
  1  63  88
z 0  69  54
y 1  27  27
t 0  98  12
  1  69  31
```

My desired output is

```
Out[19]:
      a   b
x 0   6   1
  1  63  88
t 0  98  12
  1  69  31
```

My current solution is blunt so something that can scale up more easily would be great. You can assumed a sorted index.

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df[df.level_0.duplicated() | df.level_0.duplicated(keep='last')]

Out[30]:
  level_0   a   b
0       x   6   1
1       x  63  88
0       t  98  12
1       t  69  31
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can figure this out with `groupby` (on the first level of the index) + `transform`, and then use boolean indexing to filter out those rows:

```
df[df.groupby(level=0).a.transform('size').gt(1)]

      a   b
x 0  67  83
  1   2  34
t 0  18  87
  1  63  20
```

*Details*
Output of the `groupby` -

```
df.groupby(level=0).a.transform('size')

x  0    2
   1    2
z  0    1
y  1    1
t  0    2
   1    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Filtering from here is straightforward, just find those rows with size > 1.

Answer (score 4):

Use the group by [**`filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)
You can pass a function that returns a boolean to

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

      a   b
x 0   7  33
  1  31  43
t 0  71  18
  1  68  72
```

---

I've spent my fare share of time focused on speed.  Not all solutions need to be the fastest solutions.  However, since the subject has come up.  I'll offer what I think should be a fast solution.  It is my intent to keep future readers informed.

**Results of Time Test**

```
res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0).T

                      10         30         100         300         1000         3000
cs                4.425970   4.643234   5.422120    3.768960    3.912819     3.937120
wen               2.617455   4.288538   6.694974   18.489803   57.416648   148.860403
jp                6.644870  21.444406  67.315362  208.024627  569.421257  1525.943062
pir               6.043569  10.358355  26.099766   63.531397  165.032540   404.254033
pir_pd_factorize  1.153351   1.132094   1.141539    1.191434    1.000000     1.000000
pir_np_unique     1.058743   1.000000   1.000000    1.000000    1.021489     1.188738
pir_best_of       1.000000   1.006871   1.030610    1.086425    1.068483     1.025837
```

**Simulation Details**

```
def pir_pd_factorize(df):
    f, u = pd.factorize(df.index.get_level_values(0))
    m = np.bincount(f)[f] > 1
    return df[m]

def pir_np_unique(df):
    u, f = np.unique(df.index.get_level_values(0), return_inverse=True)
    m = np.bincount(f)[f] > 1
    return df[m]

def pir_best_of(df):
    if len(df) > 1000:
        return pir_pd_factorize(df)
    else:
        return pir_np_unique(df)

def cs(df):
    return df[df.groupby(level=0).a.transform('size').gt(1)]

def pir(df):
    return df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

def wen(df):
    s=df.a.count(level=0)
    return df.loc[s[s>1].index.tolist()]

def jp(df):
    return df.loc[[i for i in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique() if len(df.loc[i]) > 1]]


res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000],
    columns='cs wen jp pir pir_pd_factorize pir_np_unique pir_best_of'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
for i in res.index:
    d = pd.DataFrame(
        dict(a=range(i)),
        pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
            np.random.randint(i // 4 * 3, size=i),
            range(i)
        ])
    )
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = f'{j}(d)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import d, {j}'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)
```

Comment: The selected answer was about twice as fast (`%timeit`) as the one proposed here although in essence the two are identical. Thanks!

Comment: I'm aware.  Thanks for the heads up (-: This answer represents using the api for its intended purpose.  There are many different ways to accomplish many of these tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Just a new way

```
s=df.a.count(level=0)

df.loc[s[s>1].index.tolist()]
Out[12]: 
      a   b
x 0   1  31
  1  70  29
t 0  42  26
  1  96  29
```

And if you want to keep using duplicate

```
s=df.index.get_level_values(level=0)

df.loc[s[s.duplicated()].tolist()]
Out[18]: 
      a   b
x 0   1  31
  1  70  29
t 0  42  26
  1  96  29
```

Comment: I like this. This actually does not use groupby. Well done.

Comment: In fact, you can simplify this further: `df[df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]` Once again, wonderful answer, good job.

Comment: Worth mentioning: If your groups aren't sorted, you will have to call `reset_index()` first.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis yep, nice tips :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced `groupby` is necessary:

```
df = df.sort_index()
df.loc[[i for i in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique() if len(df.loc[i]) > 1]]

#       a   b
# x 0  16   3
#   1  97  36
# t 0   9  18
#   1  37  30
```

Some benchmarking:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).sort_index()

def cs(df):
    return df[df.groupby(level=0).a.transform('size').gt(1)]

def pir(df):
    return df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

def wen(df):
    s=df.a.count(level=0)
    return df.loc[s[s>1].index.tolist()]

def jp(df):
    return df.loc[[i for i in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique() if len(df.loc[i]) > 1]]

%timeit cs(df)   # 19.5ms
%timeit pir(df)  # 33.8ms
%timeit wen(df)  # 17.0ms
%timeit jp(df)   # 22.3ms
```

Comment: On my computer, the other answers are at least 25 times faster.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky, Sure. I'm no pandas expert. I'm just stating I'm not convinced `groupby` is the answer. It is possible to slice a MultiIndex, though I couldn't manage it.

Comment: If you're convincing yourself that a (relatively) poor solution should be used instead of a (relatively) better solution, you'd need fantastic convincing skills ;)

Comment: Chill, I'm not defending my solution :) - although I don't see the 25x performance differential. But there are often other ways to approach a problem. I notice nobody even attempted to slice the MultiIndex.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis just out of curiosity, why do you use `df.copy()` in your benchmarking. If i understand correctly then we are returning slices of the dataframe. I wonder because it would seem that `copy` adds overhead to otherwise relatively quick operations.

Comment: Because it may not be as straightforward as some of the solutions posted here. Wen's comes close in terms of building a mask on the 0th level of the index. Anything else may need a more involved solution, and performance cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky. Short answer- I was too lazy to check for in-place operations :) - but i'll update.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis sorry, I also just noticed that within your and Wen's solution you index within the function. I think we can sort the index out of the functions since it is rather strange to have unsorted multi-level indexes anyway. Do you think it would be useful for benchmarking  to move `df.sort_index()` out of the functions and place it under the `concat` operation?

Comment: @GeneBurinsky, done. so for sorted indices, wen & my solutions are performant.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky See my post for additional methods if speed is your concern.